# Why did Luke leave his landspeeder when Sandpeople were coming?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, luke-skywalker, character-motivation

When Luke and C3PO find R2D2 in the canyon area, R2D2 informs them of several life forms headed their way.  Luke concludes they must be sandpeople, so he...

***Leaves the landspeeder and heads for a nearby cliff a few hundred feet away?***

If the three of them had just gotten into the landspeeder when R2D2 told them about the approaching sandpeople, they could've been out of there before the sandpeople had a time to walk up to the speeder, slowly investigate it, and follow Luke up to the cliff for their ambush.

**Why did Luke feel the need to lead the two droids away from their only mode of transportation, and an easy means of escape?**

Comment: wibbly wobbly forcey worcy?

Comment: those sand people are crack shots when it comes to hitting moving targets,(podracers) it must be common knowledge by now to abandon your vehicle and hide lol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like many males his age, young Luke Skywalker is rather brash and reckless - often rushing into action without thought. When faced with a threat, he would much rather confront it than avoid it. This can be seen throughout his character arc, and ultimately led to the disastrous events at Cloud City three years later when he

> ignored the advice of both Yoda and Obi-wan Kenobi, choosing to confront Vader instead of waiting to see how things turned out.

When informed of the approaching Sand People, Luke grabs his rifle and climbs the nearby ridge, hiding in a place from which he can ambush the Sand People as they approach the speeder. He underestimates the Sand People, however, who know exactly where he is and end up ambushing HIM instead. He was extremely lucky that the raiders left him fairly unharmed. In fact, had Ben Kenobi not showed up and scared them away, it's possible that Luke may not have survived.

This aggressive, gung-ho attitude becomes his primary obstacle in learning the ways of the Jedi. He must learn to put aside his desire to confront threats, and instead learn to avoid conflict whenever possible, or at least minimize his aggression in doing so.

Comment: You mean he's reckless?

Comment: reckless like his father was.

Comment: Indeed, 'reckless' is a better choice of words. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Late comment I know, but it occurs to me that Shimi, Anakin's mother, was *also* captured by sandpeople, and was kept alive in a tent for what was probably months, untils she died just in time for it to be dramatic.  Had Luke been caught, he *would* have survived...but whatever they do to the people the capture, it probably wouldn't have been pretty.

Answer (score 5):

The George Lucas [novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel)) of "A New Hope" explicitly addresses this issue. Luke recognised the threat but was tempted by the possibility of discovering something new in an area he'd never visited before:

> “*Oh my, sir. Artoo claims there are several creatures of unknown type
> approaching from the southeast.*”
>
> That could be another attempt by
> Artoo to distract them, but Luke couldn’t take the chance. Instantly
> he had his rifle off his shoulder and had activated the energy cell.
> He examined the horizon in the indicated direction and saw nothing.
> But then, sandpeople were experts at making themselves unseeable.
>
> Luke suddenly realized exactly how far out they were, how much ground
> the landspeeder had covered that morning. ***“I’ve never been out in this
> direction this far from the farm before,”* he informed Threepio. “*There
> are some awfully strange things living out here. Not all of them have
> been classified. It’s better to treat anything as dangerous until
> determined otherwise. Of course, if it’s something utterly new …*”**
>
> **His curiosity prodded him. In any case, this was probably just another ruse of Artoo Detoo’s. “*Let’s take a look,*” he decided.**

Comment: One of these days I'm going to break down and read the novelization. Not sure, though - that dialogue sounds nothing like the Luke Skywalker we've come to know and love. Good answer, regardless, though.

Comment: @omegacron - The novels are actually pretty good. The first one was ghost -written by Alan Dean Foster so there's some pretty hefty talent at work.